# Continuity of this function at a point

Tags: calculus, continuity

let $f(x)=x^2$ defined on $[0,1]$

my question may seem silly but i am really confused about it.

if we want to prove the continuity of $f$ at $x=1$ then we should have:

$\lim f(x)$ as x tends to $1_+ = \lim f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $1_- = f(1)$

ok we have $f(1)=1^2=1$ and $\lim f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $1_- = \lim x^2$ as $x$ tends to $1_- =1$

but what about $\lim f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $1_+$ ???? we dont have a definition of $f$ when $x$ tends to $1$ from the right so what shall we put instead of $f(x)$ when we say that $x$ is approaching $1$ from the left??(note that we substituted $f(x)$ by $x^2$ when searching for the $\lim$ of $f$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right since in this case $x \in [0,1]$ and therefore $f$ is defined at $x$)

Comment: What course are you in? What is the definition of continuity that you are given? Specifically, what is the definition of continuity of a function at a point?

Comment: @Prototank i mentioned it in the question and i'll put it again:

if we want to prove the continuity of f at x=1 then we should have:

lim f(x) as x tends to 1+ = lim f(x) as x tends to 1- = f(1)

Comment: If the function $f$ is not defined for $x>1$, then it doesn't make sense to consider $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to prove is that when $x \rightarrow 1$ (from the left), then $f(x) \rightarrow f(1)$. That's because $f(x)$ is not defined for $x>1$.

The definition for continuity you have in mind, and which you want to use, only makes sense for a point which is internal for the interval (or for the set) over which f is defined. So it is not applicable in this case. But, e.g., it's applicable if you want to prove the continuity of $f$ in the point $x_0=1/3$ or $x_0=1/2$.

There are 2 widely-used definitions which you can use and which make sense in both cases (for internal but also for boundary points $x_0$ for the domain of $f$):

Def.1: the function f said to be continuous at a point $x_0$, if for any sequence $x_1, x_2, ... x_n, ... $ (where $x_k$ are from the domain of $f$) which is convergent and has a limit of $x_0$, the respective sequence $f(x_1), f(x_2), ..., f(x_n), $ ... is also convergent and its limit is $f(x_0)$.

Def.2: the function $f$ is said to be continuous at a point $x_0$, if for any $\epsilon > 0$, one can find a $\delta>0$ such that when $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

The second one is more popular of course. So ... just use one of these two definitions, and you will have no troubles or doubts.

Comment: so how to prove then that  when x->1 (from the left), f(x) -> f(1)??

Comment: @haidar Directly from the definition, using definition (1) or (2).

Comment: @haidar For example, if you want to use the def.2 pick any $\epsilon$ and find the respective $\delta$. And if you decide to use def.1, your statement just follows from a theorem which says that you can perform basic operations like +, -, *, / on the limits of convergent sequences. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Sequences#Theorem_.28Algebraic_Operations.29

Comment: i still dont get your point, tell me is f continous at 1 or not ?

Comment: It is continous, yes.

Comment: is it logical that a definiton of continuity(the one i mentioned in the question) is not valid here?

Comment: It is not applicable here for the points 0 and 1 (as these are boundary points). And it's quite logical: you just cannot approach 1 from the right because as far as f is concerned there's nothing on the right of 1 (these numbers are not part of the domain of f).

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with all the comments you received: there are two possible definitions, I believe:

- Either you choose to check continuity approaching the boundary points only from inside (in this case from the left)
- Or you define continuity in a closed set in the following way (this is more common in my experience): $f$ is continuous in $F$ (not necessarily open) if there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $F$ (hence $U$ open, $F \subset U$) and a function $g$ that is continuous on $U$ and satisfies $g_{|_F} = f$